# Schema hasn't been registered for model "Product"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to create a model "Product", but when I access that by the name "Product" in the Controller, it returns me this error.

**Model Product**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

**Product Controller**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = mongoose.model('Product');

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) {
        const products = await Product.find();

        return res.json(products);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the model from 'Model Product' and require it inside your 'Product controller'. Like this:

Model Product:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        url: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        createdAt: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now()
        }
      });

     module.exports=mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Product Controller

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const Product = require('path to model product.ex-../schemas/modelProduct')

    module.exports = {
      async index(req, res) {
        const products = await Product.find();

        return res.json(products);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Now it returns me "Cannot read method ".json()" of undefined"

Comment: That means there is problem with the 'res' object. Check whether you are passing correct arguments to your index function or not.